# ASP.NET Core 2.0 fails to return EF touched object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I have the following post function, which basically just takes a multipart post (fileDataModel.File is a IFormFile object) and saves the file metadata to a database and the file to hard drive.

```
    [HttpPost("filedata")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostFileData([FromForm] FileDataBindingModel fileDataModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }           

        var contactData = await _context.ContactData.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == fileDataModel.ContactId);
        if (contactData == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ContactId", "No such contact exists.");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        FileData fileData = new FileData
        {
            ContactId = fileDataModel.ContactId,
            Contact = contactData
        };

        var fileName = fileDataModel.File.FileName;

        var FileStorageDir = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "filestorage");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(FileStorageDir);
        var FileStoragePath = FileStorageDir + "\\" + DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds() + fileName;
        using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(FileStoragePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
            await fileDataModel.File.CopyToAsync(fStream);
        }
        fileData.FilePath = FileStoragePath;
        fileData.OriginalFileName = fileName;
        fileData.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

        _context.FileData.Add(fileData);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(fileData);
    }
```

Now this function works fine, does what it should, but fails to return if the return object in the Ok() has been touched by EF at some point (so specifically, fileData and contactData). Postman reports no response received. If I input any other object, it returns the object just fine. I can't seem to find the hitch, as I get no exception or anything, just a failure to return. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try testing it with a non-async version just to see if it gives back the error?

Comment: This part of the project has officially been scrapped since I wrote the question. This means I'll have to return to the problem on my own time, which has been scarce lately, but thank you, I will try your suggestion.